# What am i doing wrong connecting to MySQL? Java

Tags: java, mysql, connection

am I blind or what? Feeling tired of coding, want to analyse what am I doing wrong here.

```
    public boolean databaseValidation(String address, int port, String username, char[] password) {

    String pw = String.valueOf(password);
    System.out.println(pw);
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + address + ":" + port +  "/logctrl?user="
                + "user=" + username + "&password=" + pw );
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error connecting to database!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Connected");
    return true;

}
```

Getting error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user=root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I know my "root" account password. I'm writing it correctly.

Any help?

UPDATE:

Fixed my connection statement, got now:

```
 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: "user=" appears twice in the url you are connecting to. So instead of trying to connect with the user "root" it tries to connect with the user ""user=root".

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS my bad.. Thanks for the tip! Overall, got " Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" this now..

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that mysql requires setting the account for each and every client host separately?

Comment: @RealSkeptic created another one, seems to be working.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the connection of mysql using command -> 
mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -h HOSTNAMEORIP DATABASENAME

1) If it works fine then your code will worked fine no issues has been encountered

2) You have used username= twice so check once again to minimize the risk

Answer (score 0):

Rechecked my accounts to connect, found that password was not changed while I was trying to change it! If someone get's that either, try to double check everything!